# How to download webpage in python, url includes GET parameters

Tags: python, file, url, download

I have an URL such as

```
http://www.example-url.com/content?param1=1&param2=2
```

in particular I am testing in on

```
http://ws.parlament.ch/votes/councillors?concillorNumberFilter=2565&format=json
```

1. How do I get the content of such URL, such that the get parameters are considered as well?
2. How can I save it to file?
3. How can I access multiple URLs like this either in parallel or asynchronously (saving to file on response received callback like in JavaScript)?

I have tried

```
import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve("http://ws.parlament.ch/votes/councillors?concillorNumberFilter=2565&format=json", "file.json")
```

but I am getting a content of http://ws.parlament.ch/votes/councillors instead of the json I want.

Comment: i have tried `urllib.urlretrieve("http://www.example-url.com/content?param1=1&param2=2", "file.json")`, but it ignores the get parameters. `http://www.example-url.com/content` is downloaded instead.

Comment: Check the documentation of `urllib.urlretrieve()`. It has a `data` argument which takes the parameters using a `urlencode`

Comment: From documentation I understand that data argument is for POST requests. I have added a URL I am testing it on to the question,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [urllib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#module-urllib), but there are other libraries I know of which make it a lot easier in different situations. for example, if you want to also have user authentication done you can use [Requests](http://requests.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). 
For this situation you can use [httplib2](https://github.com/jcgregorio/httplib2) for example, here is a clean small piece of code which takes the GET into consideration ([source](https://github.com/jcgregorio/httplib2#usage)).

```
import httplib2
h = httplib2.Http(".cache")
(resp_headers, content) = h.request("http://example.org/", "GET")
```

It seems that jou need to set the user agent of the connection otherwise it will refuse to give you the data. I also use the [urllib2.Request()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.Request) instead of the standard urlretrieve() and or urlopen(), mostly because this function allows GET, POST requests and allows the user agent to be set by the programmer.

```
import urllib2, json

user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)'
header = { 'User-Agent' : user_agent }

fullurl = "http://ws.parlament.ch/votes/councillors?councillorNumberFilter=2565&format=json"
response = urllib2.Request(fullurl, headers=header)
data = urllib2.urlopen(response)
print json.loads(data.read())
```

Some extra information about [headers in python](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html#headers)

if you want to keep using httplib2 here is the code for this one:

```
import httplib2

header = { 'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)' }

fullurl = "http://ws.parlament.ch/votes/councillors?councillorNumberFilter=2565&format=json"
http = httplib2.Http(".cache")

response, content = http.request(fullurl, "GET", headers=header)
print content
```

The data printed by my last example can be saved to a file with json.dump(filename, data).

Comment: I tried `(resp_headers, content) = h.request("http://ws.parlament.ch/votes/councillors?concillorNumberFilter=2565&format=json", "GET")` but I am still geting the content as of http://ws.parlament.ch/votes/councillors with NO parameters. If parameters were considered the content should be json.

Comment: the website doesn't allow a bot to reach the data, so to resolve that I have added the correct code in my answer.